# Is it possible to run an integral as a batch and output the results to an excel file?

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations, excel

I'm running the following integral in Mathematica:

```
    Integrate[Sqrt[3.353761086869 * 10^21 * Cos[x]^2 + 3.211998952526 * 10^21 *
 Sin[x]^2], {x, theta1 (Pi/180), theta2 (Pi/180)}]
```

Where **theta1** and **theta2** starts off at **theta1 = 0.0** and **theta2 = 0.1**, then the next run would increment **theta1 = 0.1** and **theta2 = 0.2**, then the next run would be **theta1 = 0.2** and **theta2 = 0.3**, all the way up to **theta1 = 89.9** and **theta2 = 90.0**.

For example:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[3.353761086869 * 10^21 * Cos[x]^2 + 3.211998952526 * 10^21 * Sin[x]^2], {x, 0.0 (Pi/180), 0.1 (Pi/180)}] = 101074922.95397818
```

Is it possible to run this as a batch in Wolfram Alpha so that I'm not manually entering 900 queries and then is it possible to output the batched results to an excel file?

Thank you.

Comment: Questions solely about WolframAlpha are off-topic on this site. It would be on-topic if you were trying to do this with Mathematica rather than WolframAlpha.

Comment: Thank you for responding, and as I stated, I'm more than willing to try any suggestions. So how would I go about this in Mathematica?

Comment: Edit your question to show what you have tried in Mathematica rather than in WolframAlpha. You are expected to have at least a basic understanding of Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

This is  a correction to the earlier answer in which I did not correctly convert integration limits to radians:

```
(*default directory same as notebook*)
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];

(*the integral needs to be done only once*)
(*create a function*)
integral[x_] = 
  Integrate[
   Sqrt[3.353761086869*10^21*Cos[x]^2 + 
     3.211998952526*10^21*Sin[x]^2], x];

(*make a table of the result*)
result = 
  Table[{x , integral[(x + .1) Pi/180] - integral[x Pi/180]}, {x, .1, 
    89.9, .1}];

(*plot it*)
ListLinePlot[result]
```

[image]

```
(*export the result to an Excel file*)
Export["Table2.xlsx", result]
```

Comment: thank you, when I try to output to the excel file, it looks like it's trying to open this page /wolframcloud/userfiles/e08/e08a484b-36b1-4763-b8e1-ef43993b49ec/.Objects/51e/Table.xlsx, and as such gives an error. Is there a way to make it output the excel file locally to my PC? Also, will this {x, .1, 89.9, .1} cause the integral to evaluate from 0.0 to 90.0 by taking 0.1 steps?

Comment: This code is run in Mathematica installed on a PC.  It exports the Excel file to the directory the notebook was opened from. I only use Mathematica locally.

Comment: And yes. This code evaluates the integral over each of the limits. It does this by first obtaining the integral and uses that to compute the definite integrals over each interval.

Comment: I don't think the integral is working correctly. In the excel spreadsheet column A = 0.1 and column B = 5788335147, column A = 0.2, and column B = 5783580292, etc. However, what I'm looking for is the distance between any two degrees between 0.0 - 90.0. For example, between 0.0 and 0.1 I would use Integrate[Sqrt[3.353761086869 10^21 Cos[x]^2 + 3.211998952526 10^21 Sin[x]^2], {x, 0 (Pi/180), 0.1 (Pi/180)}] = 101074922.953 or (1.010749229539782 *10^8). This is the correct value, which is very different than the values the code you provided is producing (again, thank you for the help).

Comment: Yes. My bad!  I did not correctly convert degrees to radians in the integration limits. 
I’ve edited to a corrected answer.

Comment: you rock! thank you!

Comment: Just to mention the following: The reason the answer here is better than simply making a batch of ```Table[{theta1, 
  Integrate[
   Sqrt[3.353761086869*10^21*Cos[x]^2 + 
     3.211998952526*10^21*Sin[x]^2], {x, 
    theta1 (Pi/180), (theta1 + 0.1) (Pi/180)}]}, {theta1, 0, 90, 0.1}]``` is because the above method requires you to recompute the integral at every step of the way. By integrating the form first (note that David uses `=` and not `:=` when defining the integral function) you only have to simply plug numbers in.  :)